# Swiper Slider Buttons become disabled before reaching the last slide

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

Basically what I am trying to do is to have **multiple** swiper sliders, where when a slide is clicked, the whole slider switches into fullscreen mode. I found a codepen that does just that: https://codepen.io/smcgrath/pen/aydBNx

Everything works great as long as only one slider is used per page. I tried adapting the code to work for multiple instances so I wouldn't have to duplicate ids and classes since there are up to 8 instances on a page.

It kind of works, there is only 1 issue remaining that I can't figure out how to fix. Once in fullscreen mode, when using the arrows to navigate, they randomly become disabled before reaching the end of slider. It seems like swiper thinks there is only 5 slides when there are 10 for example.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is my current code:

**Part 1 - mutliple swiper instances**

```
jQuery(".hsProdSlider").each(function () {
    var currentElem = jQuery(this);
    jQuery(this)
      .find(".hsSlider .fl-module-content")
      .addClass("swiper-container");
    jQuery(this).find(".hsSlider .fl-post-feed").addClass("swiper-wrapper");
    var swiper = new Swiper(jQuery(this).find(".swiper-container"), {
      navigation: {
        nextEl: jQuery(currentElem).find(".swiperNav__next"),
        prevEl: jQuery(currentElem).find(".swiperNav__prev"),
      },
      slidesPerView: 1,
      paginationClickable: true,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      loop: false,
      breakpoints: {
        1200: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 10,
        },
      },
    });
```

**Part 2 - open in fullscreen mode**

```
jQuery(currentElem).find(".fl-post-feed-post").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).on("click tap", function () {
        var slideId = jQuery(this).parent().find(".fl-post-feed-post").index(this);
        openFullscreenSwiper(slideId, currentElem);
    });
});
```

**Part 3 - fullscreen functionality**

```
function openFullscreenSwiper(initialSlideNumber, currentElem) {
        currentElem = jQuery(currentElem)[0];
        var mainSwiperMarkup = jQuery(currentElem).find(".swiper-container").html();

        var fullscreenswiperElem = jQuery(currentElem).find(".fullscreen-swiper");
        var fullscreenswiperElemsa = jQuery(currentElem).find(".fullscreen-swiper")[0];
        fullscreenswiperElem.append(
            mainSwiperMarkup + "<div id='fullscreen-swiper-close' class='fullscreen-swiper-close'>X</div>"
        ).fadeIn();

        var fullscreenSwiper = new Swiper(jQuery(fullscreenswiperElem), {
            navigation: {
                nextEl: jQuery(currentElem).find(".swiperNav__next"),
                prevEl: jQuery(currentElem).find(".swiperNav__prev"),
            },
            slidesPerView: 1,
            centeredSlides: true,
            paginationClickable: true,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            loop: false,
            initialSlide: initialSlideNumber,
        });


        jQuery(currentElem).find(".fullscreen-swiper-backdrop").fadeIn();
        jQuery("body, html").addClass("no-scroll swiperFull");


    }

    jQuery("body").on("click", ".fullscreen-swiper-close", function () {
        var closeelem = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".fullscreen-swiper-backdrop");
        jQuery(this).parent().hide().empty();
        closeelem.fadeOut();
        jQuery("body, html").removeClass("no-scroll swiperFull");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Martin, Did you find a way to fix this? if yes can you please share it here, So others with same issue can solve it(like me :))